# Can't turn datetime string into datetime object - ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, strptime

```
date_time_str = data['date']
date_time_obj = dt.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(date_time_obj)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: time data 'date' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

But the string datetime is the same exact format as I formatted above:

```
"2020-08-30 20:29:42"
```

Comment: But the string `'date'` is not in that format

Comment: Do you mean the ```data['date']``` ?

Comment: The error message says that the string you're trying to parse is `'date'`.

Comment: Look at the error. It means you are trying to convert the string `'date'` to a date, which is clearly not what you meant to do. Check why `data['date']` is `'date'`

Comment: you could add `print(date_time_str)` before to be sure of how it looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is not this `dt.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`.
It looks like data['date'] is a time data.